# Allow Putty store passwords

Tags: ssh, passwords, putty

Is there any way to allow Putty to store passwords? Please note that safety is not an issue (private LAN), so the easiest solution would be to save the password in the Putty session (instead of using keys or the `-pw` option).

I know there is a way to do so, but I don't remember how to do so, and all the posts I've found showed how to do it using the `-pw` flag or with keys.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with PuTTY without as you note creating a shortcut and using the -pw option. There is a fork of PuTTY called [KiTTY](http://kitty.9bis.com/) that will allow you to configure a password.

Comment: FWIW - I found this comment here and tried KiTTY also. It is exactly what I needed for similar situation.

Answer (score 12):

No.

Might I refer you to PuTTY's own FAQ for this?

http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/faq.html#faq-password-remember

The documentation does specify a `-pw` option (just for SSH):
http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.62/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline

However, as the FAQ suggests, you should look into setting up public-key auth - it's quite simple, safe and elegant.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to be able to log on automatically without using passwords, why not logon using a private key instead?

You can use puttygen to generate the keys, as described [here](http://katsande.com/using-puttygen-to-generate-ssh-private-public-keys)

Once you have your key files in the right places, you will not be prompted for a password.

See also http://tartarus.org/~simon/putty-snapshots/htmldoc/Chapter8.html#pubkey

Comment: There's a number of reasons for NOT using public key authentication, first and most obvious one being because your device does not support it.

Answer (score 3):

Not directly but as a workaround for this I always start with WinSCP and start PuTTY from there, with WinSCP passing the credentials through. It's only two extra clicks of the mouse.

Answer (score 2):

I use mRemoteNG to wrap Putty connections, it saves the passwords plus combines all sessions into a nicely manageable UI.

Answer (score 1):

[Putty connection manager](https://www.technlg.net/windows/download-putty-and-connection-manager/) can store usernames and passwords. It also enables tabbed putty sessions.

Answer (score 1):

If what you really want to do is just log on with SSH automatically, you can try Pageant. In Putty settings -> Connection -> SSH -> Auth, there is an option "Attempt authentication using Pageant". So what you can do is just start Pageant, add your SSH private key into it and you are good to go.